# TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync always fails for me in Asp.Net Identity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync always fails even though a record in `[dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]` exists.

[image: Table screenshot]

Hello,

I have been able to generate the recovery code successfully and I can see the entry in the database within `[dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]` table

This is the code to login:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginWithRecoveryCode(LoginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel loginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(loginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel);
    }

    var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");
    }

    var recoveryCode = Regex.Replace(loginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel.RecoveryCode, "\\s+", ";");

    var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync(recoveryCode);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return LocalRedirect(loginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel.ReturnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/"));
    }          
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid recovery code entered.");
        return View(loginwithRecoveryCodeViewModel);
    }
}
```

It always goes into `Failed` block. Notice this block. I am trying to replace the code with space with ; as the database table contains ; as shown in the screenshot. But I also tried with `string.empty` instead of `;` and yet it wouldn't succeed.

Comment: do you mean you want to replace the `;` with ` ` in the `RecoveryCode`? And because of the convert is failed so `result.Succeeded` is false? is it possible to convert  the recovery code into string and replace content in string?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer. You get 10 codes and you need to use each code one by one meaning one code for 1 login. I thought I need to use the entire bunch in one go.

Comment: I would suggest that you provide example code.